# Android Studio connection MongoDB: Gradle build finished with 1 error

Tags: java, android, linux, mongodb, gradle

I need help to setup a **direct** connection to a **MongoDB database** (locally) using **Android Studio** on a Linux Mint 17.1 machine.

I made a new & clean project in Android Studio as you can see below.

[image: Clean project]

After that I made new Java Class with the following code:

```
package com.example.bebo.connection;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

import java.util.Set;

public class MongoPortal {

    public boolean insert(){

        try {
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27107 );

            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");

            // Get and print all the collections
            Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();
            for (String s : colls)
                System.out.println(s);

            mongoClient.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Last but not least, I changed the dependencies at build.gradle(Module: app) to:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

**Building..**
Output:

[image]

I just need the easiest way to setup a connection, but I can't figure out what I am missing here. Everything is installed correctly as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me twice both the times the problem was with dependencies. This as far as I know this happens if you have same library with different versions (for me it was appcompat) or if you forget to list any dependency that needs to be listed.

Can you verify all jar files you have in lib folder (worst case by removing one by one) and also check dependencies once. Especially appcompat.

hope this helps.

Comment: ty for your quick response. I think it helps, because I only have one .jar file and thats the mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar

Comment: Looking at the structure, I am guessing appcompat was added as dependency when you created activity as it extends to actionBarActivity. if yes, Can you make it normal Activity and comment out this dependency and build this once (to make sure if its appcompat which is causing problems)?  
if not, please remove one by one dependencies and try to build.

Comment: I've found the problem. When I comment out **'compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.0.0'** the application will build and launch on my Android-phone. So I need to add the correct dependency for the driver

Comment: Good to know :) i could not find any other best way than removing dependencies one by one. Please update this page in case if you find any more easier way

Comment: Hey guys! Did you fixed the problem after all? I have the same problem and cannnot find a solutin 2 days now..

Comment: Hey have you verified if your dependncies are proper?